# WTForms use quotes in Jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

I've got the following WTForms class:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField

class MonitorLevel(FlaskForm):
    monitor = SelectField('Monitor', choices=MONITOR_CHOICES)
```

Which can be rendered using the following jinja2-code:

```
{{ form.monitor() }}
```

However, I want to execute a JS-script when the value changes, so I've added the following:

```
{{ form.monitor(**{'onchange': 'sendForm();'}) }}
```

Which works fine, but now I want to pass a variable (which is a string), as an argument:

```
{{ form.monitor(**{'onchange': 'sendForm("{}");'.format(variable)}) }}
```

However, this renders as:

```
<select id="monitor" name="monitor" onchange="sendForm(&quot;name&quot;);">...</select>
```

So, I tried to escape this using the `safe` function, but this doesn't work. I've also tried to escape the quote by: \", but that doesn't work as well.

Any ideas of adding a quote in the value of the dict?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what would give `{{ form.monitor(**{'onchange': 'sendForm("");'}) }}` ?

Answer (score 1):

From the WTForms documentation https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/widgets/#widget-building-utilities :

> WTForms uses [MarkupSafe](https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe) to escape unsafe HTML characters before rendering. You can mark a string using `markupsafe.Markup` to indicate that it should not be escaped.

Without using `markupsafe.Markup` I had the same error:

```
{{ input_field(**{'@click': '"show=true"'})|safe }}
```

gives

```html
<input @click="&#34;show=true&#34;">
```

instead of

```html
<input @click="'show=true'">
```

Using the `markupsafe` module inside the Jinja2 template:

```
{{ input_field(**{'@click': markupsafe.Markup("show=true")})|safe }}
```

does the job:

```html
<input @click="show=true">
```

---

**Be careful**: WTForm encloses the string in the double quotes `"`, so you need to take a usual care about the `"` inside your string.

**BAD WAY**

```
{{ input_field(**{'@click': markupsafe.Markup('console.log("show=true")')})|safe }}
```

will result in

```html
<input @click="console.log("show=true")">
```

which is wrong (one string is not inside the other).

**GOOD WAY**

```
{{ input_field(**{'@click': markupsafe.Markup("console.log('show=true')")})|safe }}
```

will give

```html
<input @click="console.log('show=true')"
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal, WTForms use `escape(s, quote=True)` to render HTML attributes values ([escape documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html))

You can look function `def html_params(**kwargs):` on [Github directly](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/widgets/core.py) fore more informations.

Basically you don't have to change your code because :

1. Javascript still works like a charm, your browser transforms HTML entities on the fly (`sendForm()` is run `onchange`).
2. `onchange="sendForm("name");"` is NOT valid HTML attribute if you print it without `escape(s, quote=True)`.